# Can't generate coverage report in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, code-coverage

I want to generate a coverage report from IDEA/ I've seen [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code-coverage-report.html) instruction and a lot of other. But I simply don't have this button in the Coverage tool window or in any other places.
[my coverage tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UCry.png)

Has anyone been able to solve a similar problem?

`idea.log` afret running with coverage:

```
2023-09-13 11:47:48,294 [11997474]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /snap/intellij-idea-community/454/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar

2023-09-13 11:47:54,014 [12003194]   WARN - #c.i.u.t.AsyncTreeModel - ignore duplicated child at 7: ru.projectname.ws.user.test

2023-09-13 11:48:59,376 [12068556]   INFO - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - waitedInQueueNs(-2784) | executionDurationNs(2316375) is negative -> unexpected state

2023-09-13 11:49:25,644 [12094824]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files

2023-09-13 11:49:25,672 [12094852]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS)

2023-09-13 11:49:25,678 [12094858]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /home/victoria/Desktop/unit/ru.projectname.ws.user

2023-09-13 11:49:25,690 [12094870]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is closed

2023-09-13 11:49:25,690 [12094870]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - KCRI storage is closed (didn't exist)

2023-09-13 11:49:26,023 [12095203]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened

2023-09-13 11:49:26,025 [12095205]   WARN - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - kotlin-data-container is not found

2023-09-13 11:49:26,138 [12095318]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompilerUtil -   COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 671 ms: 0 min 0sec

2023-09-13 11:49:26,394 [12095574]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

2023-09-13 11:49:26,394 [12095574]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.JulLogger (file:/snap/intellij-idea-community/454/lib/util-8.jar) to field java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks

2023-09-13 11:49:26,394 [12095574]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.JulLogger

2023-09-13 11:49:26,394 [12095574]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

2023-09-13 11:49:26,394 [12095574]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

2023-09-13 11:49:26,478 [12095658]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /snap/intellij-idea-community/454/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar

2023-09-13 11:49:30,910 [12100090]   WARN - #c.i.u.t.AsyncTreeModel - ignore duplicated child at 7: ru.projectname.ws.user.test
```

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue. Is coverage data shown in tool window?